# Thread pool useful with Intel Threading Building Blocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I have a thread pool that I made to work with pthreads, now that I'm looking into using Intel® Threading Building Blocks (TBB) I'm wondering if there is any point keeping my thread pool and making it work with TBB?

Comment: You're not giving much detail. What do you mean by "I'm wondering if there is any point keeping my thread pool"? Are you asking if TBB already implements the functionality of your thread pool?

Comment: @Tudor Yes, does TBB have a thread pool? If not, will I mess up things like the TBB cpu cache miss optimizer, malloc multithreading etc

Comment: TBB uses a model similar to the .NET TPL: you create instances of `task` which are executed on an underlying thread pool: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00166.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the short answer is no.